# Serial Communication on Windows 7 via Bluetooth has intermittent data loss

Tags: windows, bluetooth, serial-communication

Currently I'm working on a portal device, which communicates with Windows via bluetooth serial communication.
It works fine on windows 10.
But on windows 7, things get strange, the communication is not stable, sometimes it runs well for a whole day, sometimes it lose data frequently. The bluetooth driver version on two platforms is the same. I have no idea how to solve it.
Are there any reasons?

Comment: Would be great to know how you use Bluetooth: Is is Serial Port or WinSock or specific driver's functions? Also how do you process received data and what is the size of data?

Comment: Even if I use a serial comm test tool to send commands directly, the problem may still remain.

Comment: How do you send it? Possible problem is that WriteFile() and send() functions send not all data. For example if you send 1Mb of data the function sends only 100 bytes (and returns ampunt of sent bytes). So your code must always analize result and send next data part if function was not able to send all the data. The same on receiving side. Even your send function sent all 100 bytes on receiving side it may receive only 10 bytes, then next 20 bytes, then next 5 and so on. So you must always know data length and receive in correct way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The length of data sent each time is shorter than 15 bytes. And in the case of data loss, I received nothing. BTW, I use function WriteFile and ReadFile to send and receive data.

Comment: Its hard to say what can be wrong without looking at the code but in fact we have never faced such issue. You can try to test it with [Bluetooth Framework](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm). It uses other communication method (not vCOM) so helps to exclude vCOM issue.